# Hartshorne Proposition 2.7.7

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

There are 2 claims in this Proposition that I can't see. In the proof of part b) he writes $(f) \geq -D_0$ thus $f$ gives a global section of $\mathcal L(D_0)$ How does this follow? I think having something like $f|_{U_i} \cdot f_i \in \mathcal O_X(U_i)$ gives it but I don't know how that follows from $(f) \geq -D_0$.

Then in part c) he says that since $X$ is a projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ the global sections are isomorphic to $k$. How can you show this?

[image: Proposition 2.7.7]

Comment: Your question for (c) is answered at the end of the sentence. See Theorem 3.4.

Comment: How do you pass from the 'variety' case to the scheme case though?

Comment: Is the word "scheme" mentioned anywhere before you brought it up?

Comment: The definition of variety in chapter 2 is an integral separated scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: For (b): Let $g$ be a local equation for $D$ on an open subset $U$ of $X$. Then $\mathcal{L}(D)|_U=\mathcal{O}_U\cdot g^{-1}$, so a rational function $f$ belongs to $\mathcal{L}(D)(U)$ if and only if $(fg)\geq 0$, i.e. $(f)\geq -(g)=-D|_U$.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was looking at but how does $(fg) \geq 0$ imply $f$ is in that set? Because the valuation occurs on some local ring of $\mathcal O_X(U)$, like we have for all primes $Y$ st $Y \cap U \neq \emptyset, v_Y(f \cdot g) \geq 0$.

Comment: Becaus $X$ is normal, see [[Tag 031T](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031T)].

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Do you happen to know how to do the other part of my question as well?